# Placebo treatment as specification and estimation test?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Consider a multiple linear regression. As an econometrician, my aim is to make sure the model is well-specified and my estimations are consistent-efficient. I know there are tests for most if not all of the potential problems in a regression. I'm thinking on an extra test, based on a **placebo treatment**. By placebo treatment I mean to generate a random dummy that affects only half of the observations. By definition, its coefficient should be insignificant. Thus, by bootstrapping over the treatment, it is possible to see the % of times the null is rejected.

Consider the following hypothesis:

$H_{0}$: model correctly specified and estimated.

$H_{1}$: model mis-specified and/or estimation method incorrect.

Consider the statistic $\Gamma(n)$, which gives the proportion of null rejections of the placebo variable on the regression. $n$ is the number of bootstrap iterations. Under the null above ($H_{0}$), then $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Gamma(n) = \alpha$$ where $\alpha$ is the Type I error. I do not see how, under the null, an alternative outcome for the limit is possible.

Alternatively, under $H_{1}$ the model is incorrectly specified, or the method is not consistent/efficient. Then, the question is, will $\Gamma(n)$ **never** converge to $\alpha$? For example, if the model is correct, but I do not account for serial correlation (e.g. using OLS instead of GLS), standard errors of placebo effect will be wrong. Under this case it is expected that $\Gamma(n)$ will not converge to $\alpha$. But it could be that other problems do not affect the estimation of the placebo parameter (I cannot think on an example). If these cases exist, then it is possible that Type II error under the null will increase. Does this invalidate the method?

So sum up, is a placebo treatment a **valid** mechanism to evaluate regression problems?

Comment: This approach reminds me of instrumental variable analysis: http://ije.oxfordjournals.org/content/29/4/722.full What is the difference between the two approaches?